# Wordcloud is not showing up while fetching the database from GridDB container?

Tags: griddb

I am using the matplotlib wordcloud function for the tweet data fetched from the GridDB container. But after running the below code, all I get is a blank graph screen with no wordcloud.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1
    ).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.show()

show_wordcloud(tweet_dataframe)
```

Any help would be appreciated?